# How to add two sensors in ros + gazebo

Tags: ros, robotics

I followed a tutorial found here: https://bharat-robotics.github.io/blog/adding-hokuyo-laser-to-turtlebot-in-gazebo-for-simulation/

I successfully added Hokuyo sensor to my turtlebot but I'm not sure how to add both Kinect and Hokuyo.

I have to run this command:

```
export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR="hokuyo"
```

In order to set Hokuyo as my sensor. But is there a way I can set both kinect and hokuyo?